# KotlinMultiPlatform Error: Could not create task ':shared:linkSharedReleaseFrameworkIos'

Tags: ios, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I have a KotlinMultiplatform shared library project. it was building perfectly with Kotlin 1.6 and AndroidGradlePlugin 7.0.4.

As soon as I migrated my project with Kotlin Version 1.8.21 and AndroidGradlePlugin version 7.4.2. It started throwing

```
Build file '/Users/ashwanikumar/Documents/porter/customerapp-shared/shared/build.gradle.kts' line: 23

Could not create task ':shared:linkSharedReleaseFrameworkIos'.
> Could not create task of type 'KotlinNativeLink'.
   > Configuration with name 'iosSharedReleaseFrameworkExport' not found.

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer$TaskCreationException: Could not create task ':shared:linkSharedReleaseFrameworkIos'.
```

below is my build.gradle file code.

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.mpp.KotlinNativeTarget
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.mpp.NativeBuildType

configurations.create("compileClasspath")

plugins {
  id(CustomerAppSharedPlugins.androidLibraryPlugin)
  id(CustomerAppSharedPlugins.androidJunit5Plugin)
  id(CustomerAppSharedPlugins.testLoggerPlugin)
  id(CustomerAppSharedPlugins.kotlinxSerialization)
}

android {
  compileSdkVersion(CustomerAppSharedAndroidConfig.compileSdkVersion)
  defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion(CustomerAppSharedAndroidConfig.minSdkVersion)
  }
}

kotlin {
  iosArm64("ios") { // iosX64, iosArm64
    binaries {
      framework("shared", listOf(NativeBuildType.RELEASE)) {
        freeCompilerArgs += "-Xobjc-generics"
        freeCompilerArgs += "-Xg0" 
      }
    }
  }

  android {
    publishLibraryVariants("release", "debug")
  }

  sourceSets[CustomerAppSharedSourceSets.commonMain].dependencies {
    api(CustomerAppSharedLibs.Common.Main.KMPUtils.commons)
  }

  sourceSets[CustomerAppSharedSourceSets.androidMain].dependencies {
    api(CustomerAppSharedLibs.Android.Main.ktorOkHttp)
  }

  sourceSets[CustomerAppSharedSourceSets.androidTest].dependencies {
    implementation(CustomerAppSharedLibs.Common.Main.KMPUtils.testing)
  }
}

val packForXcode by tasks.creating(Sync::class) {
  val targetDir = File(buildDir, "xcode-frameworks")

  val mode = System.getenv("CONFIGURATION") ?: "RELEASE"
  val framework = kotlin.targets
    .getByName<KotlinNativeTarget>("ios")
    .binaries.getFramework("shared", "RELEASE")

  inputs.property("mode", mode)
  dependsOn(framework.linkTask)

  from({ framework.outputDirectory })
  into(targetDir)

  doLast {
    val gradlew = File(targetDir, "gradlew")
    gradlew.writeText(
      "#!/bin/bash\n" +
        "export 'JAVA_HOME=${System.getProperty("java.home")}'\n" +
        "cd '${rootProject.rootDir}'\n" +
        "./gradlew \$@\n",
    )
    gradlew.setExecutable(true)
  }
}

tasks.getByName("build").dependsOn(packForXcode)

tasks.withType<org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile>().all {
  kotlinOptions.freeCompilerArgs += "-Xopt-in=kotlin.RequiresOptIn"
}
```

Note: I tried creating a new project with same configs it's working fine. Also I tried Invalidating cache, clean build, rebuild.